# Free MySQL result and close connection on throw Exception

Tags: php, mysql, exception

Is it important to free MySQL result with `mysql_free_result` and close MySQL connection with `mysql_close` before throw `Exception`? Or PHP does it automatically?

Comment: As far as I know, when you look at the manual pages of the function names you have in your question, you should be able to find that and good to know related information directly. Just writing this, because it's not clear from your question what your current status of obtaining knowledge about your issue is. Also have you tried to search for your question title and the keywords?

Comment: If you are throwing exceptions you are writing OO code. If you are writing OO code you should use an OO database interface. Please use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php), you must always free your result using `mysqli_free_result`

As for closing the connection using `mysql_close`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058019/how-often-should-i-close-database-connections) is an earlier discussion regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't close your connection explicitly, PHP will automatically close the connection when your script ends.

See under “Description” here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php

Note that for persistent database connections, it is not the case. Read here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php